# TYPO3 Extension Manager: Button "Only display updatable extensions" is not displayed

Tags: typo3

If I open the extension manager, switch to the tab `Import Extensions` and select the filter I get the following options:

- `Display all extensions` (empty)
- `Only display installed extensions` (working)

There should also be a `Only display updatable extensions` selection but this isn't displayed. What is the reason therefore?

I made a TYPO3 update to 4.7.2 and perhaps thats the reason why it isn't correctly displayed?

The repository is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter has been moved from the `Import Extensions` to the `Available Extensions` tab.

You do not actually want to import an extension, but update an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Just suggestion: I had similar issues with button displaying in EM before (4.6.x) (ie. Install ext button) and realised, that the button is available, but sprite image had wrong position which caused that the button was transparent,

Try to use ie FireBug to check it, and eventually fix the CSS (and report the bug)

**Edit:**

Some doom apparently, I just had identical situation just seconds ago ;) Fortunately found the reason: the ext list is displayed with ExtJS grid, which can contain custom filtering per column. Literally: when you for an example click on the column's dropdown arrow, you can in its filter set some value to narrow the search results.

Ie.: in the main filter field write `news` and additionally in the `Extension Key` column set other filter `tt_news`. (if you want to display only `%tt_news%` in result list of `%news%`)

In that case even if you'll clear the main filter, the one set on the column will stay active, so next time when you'll try to search  for `realurl` in main filter, it will return empty list as `Extension Key` filter is still set to `tt_news`.

Weeeird, however helped me :)

You can recognize filtered columns as their names are written with *cursive*, finally you can just check every column and disable any filtering on each.

Comment: I saw only two `li` elements ... So the selection is completely missing. Is there another way to update the extensions? Perhaps manually? If I right click it there is a menu popping up with the text `Import versions of "xxx" (14 versions available)`. Is this the right way?

Comment: @testing: Hm , I just met identical problem, in my case it was additional filtering, check my edit for more details.

Comment: I tried it and deleted all filters, but I still can't see the entry. I looked on other Typo3 4.7.2 and 4.7.1 projects and also the entry is missing. There are no cursive columns at all ... Has this feature been removed? Edit: Ahh, there is a update symbol in front of the extension icon and name. I think that would work. Lets try it.